# How to group row wise in a dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe and I want to group them in 1000 rows in each group and then I want to find the max and min of each group and finally save both min and max row of each group in a new dataframe.

I have tried various options but no luck. I am fairly naive to pandas.

```
df.groupby(df['col_name'] // 1000).apply(max)
```

and another one was,

```
k = 1000 
res = df.col_name[::-1].rolling(k,1).max().shift(1)[::-1]

pd.concat([df.col_name, res], axis = 1)
```

[image]

If above is my dataframe and suppose I want 3 rows in each group. The new dataframe should be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `groupby` and `stack`

```
df.groupby(df.index//3).agg(['first', 'last']).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Your solution works fine for df.index//3, but when I change it to 4, its not giving the right solution.

Comment: What's your expected result when use `df.index//4`? Is it not right?

Comment: its always giving me first row.

Comment: Basically it giving only first and last row of the stack but I want min and max of each stack.

Comment: Actually I want min max from each stack. I tried using sort_values after group by but its giving me error.

Comment: I can't understand `min max` mean. beacause there is a column which type is string. if you want to get min max by weight and age, you can make a new column by df.index//4 to mark the group and then sort the dataframe by groupmark column and weight and age and then use groupby and stack.

Comment: Based on your previous suggestion I used:       df.groupby(df.index//5).agg(['min', 'max']).stack(), which is giving me some what i want but not preserving the order. Are you able to answer me, why this is giving min max for Age column and is it possible to preserve the order of min and max according to their appearance in the dataframe.